# how can I use a variable for the count in a FullSeriesCollection(1)

Tags: excel, vba, count, graphing

I want to load an xy graph in excel(2013) using vba with 200 sets of X and Y data. I want to change the "count" number at the end of the "FullSeriesCollection(i)" using a variable but it seems this will not work and what ever I do the system allocates its own count number. A search tells me "Count" is read  only. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

I am trying to do this:

```
Dim j as long
for J = 1 to 200
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4104").Activate
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(j).XValues = "='side A'!$g$j:$k$j"
  ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(j).Values = "='side A'!$g$(j+1):$k$(j+1)"
```

etc. etc.

Comment: The way "around it" is to add or remove members in the `SeriesCollection`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do this:

Dim j as long
for J = 1 to 200
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4104").Activate
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(j).XValues = "='side A'!$g$j:$k$j"
  ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(j).Values = "='side A'!$g$(j+1):$k$(j+1)"
etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `SeriesCollection.Add` method returns a reference to the added series, so you can use that:

```
Dim j as long, s

for J = 1 to 200

    Set s = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4104").Chart.SeriesCollection.Add()

      s.XValues = "='side A'!$g$j:$k$j"
      s.Values = "='side A'!$g$(j+1):$k$(j+1)"
```